# Enabled/disabled buttons when one checkbox or more are checked

Tags: javascript, html

To do this, I have a javascript file that count how many checkboxes in my form are checked, then:

- if nothing is checked, these buttons: Change, delete, reset password will be disabled.
- if one is checked, those will be all enabled.
- if two or more is checked, Change will be disabled, the rest will still be enabled.

But in reality all of them stay disabled no matter what I do, so I wonder what I did wrong here.
Here is my code:

html:

```
 <form action="" name="tform" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3" align="right">
                        <input type="text" name="search_value" size="35"/><input type="submit" name="Search_clicked" value="Search"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <table class="sortable" id="sortable_example" border="2">
                            <tr>
                            <th class="unsortable">Select</th>
                            <th>UserID</th>
                            <th>User name</th>
                            <th>Enable/Disable</th>
                            <th>Start date</th>
                            <th>End date</th>
                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="userid[]" value="1"/></td>
                <td>00001</td>
                <td>trang</td>
                <td>Enable</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
            </tr>                <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="userid[]" value="11"/></td>
                <td>00011</td>
                <td>trangnt00914@fpt.edu.vn</td>
                <td>Enable</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
            </tr>                <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="userid[]" value="12"/></td>
                <td>00012</td>
                <td>apgs1104@gmail.com</td>
                <td>Enable</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
            </tr>                <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="userid[]" value="13"/></td>
                <td>00013</td>
                <td>congchua_cambuagietchim@yahoo.</td>
                <td>Enable</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
            </tr>                <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="userid[]" value="14"/></td>
                <td>00014</td>
                <td>apgs1234@gmail.com</td>
                <td>Enable</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
            </tr>                <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="userid[]" value="15"/></td>
                <td>00015</td>
                <td>apgs1104@yahoo.com</td>
                <td>Enable</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
            </tr>                <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="userid[]" value="16"/></td>
                <td>00016</td>
                <td>trang1104@gmail.com</td>
                <td>Enable</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
                <td>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr height="100px">
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Add_clicked" value="Add"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Add_massively_clicked" value="Add massively"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Change_clicked" disabled value="Change"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Delete_clicked" disabled onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" value="Delete"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Reset_password_clicked" disabled onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" value="Reset password"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>     
            </form>
```

and javascript:

```
var obj;
var count=0;
var Change = document.getElementsByName('Change_clicked')[0];
var Delete = document.getElementsByName('Delete_clicked')[0];
var Reset_password = document.getElementsByName('Reset_password_clicked')[0];
    for (var i=0; i<tform.elements.length; i++) {
      obj = tform.elements[i];
      if (obj.type == "checkbox" && obj.checked) {
        count++;
      }
    }

if(count==0){
    Change.disabled=true;
    Delete.disabled=true;
    Reset_password.disabled=true;
}
if(count==1){
    Change.disabled=false;
    Delete.disabled=false;
    Reset_password.disabled=false;
}
if(count>1){
    Change.disabled=true;
    Delete.disabled=false;
    Reset_password.disabled=false;
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: is this the complete code ? You never execute javascript when clicking on a checkbox ?

Comment: This is the completed code. I thought it will execute automatically without having to call it, I'm new to javascript. Thank you, ur question solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, *the only thing you missed to wrap it to a function and add an event handler.*

1) Using **`onchange`** event handler, for your **`checkboxes`**

***example:***

```
<input type="checkbox"  onchange="fun()" name="userid[]" value="1"/>
```

2) Wrap your code to a function like

```
function fun() {
  //add your code
}
```

See it is working in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L79H7/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think of this. Just waiting for 2 minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: @Mee Glad to hear it helped you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of using:

```
<input type="submit" name="Change_clicked" disabled value="Change"/>
```

just:

```
<input type="submit" name="Change_clicked" value="Change"/>
```

for each button and then on `document.ready` and `onclick()` event within a checkbox check the amount of enabled check boxes. Then apply your settings from your function.

Also instead of using

```
var Change = document.getElementsByName('Change_clicked')[0];
```

just use ids with your elements because they are present only once:

```
var Change = document.getElementsById('Change_clicked');
```

Edit: instead of `onclick()` trigger the function by `onChange()`, kudos to @Praveen

Comment: for radio button and checkboxes, `onchange` will be the correct event handler.  Also OP code of using tagName is correct.  You can check the fiddle in my answer to see it working.

Comment: Yes, you're right I've edited it in.. `onchange()` is more suitable for this